# is using " require_once " affect the speed of the website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I am working on a framework to make my workflow faster like a starter theme plus boilerplate. so one of main parts that will make the work faster is the plurality ...

I for example in function.php when I need to create new post type instead of writing a big block of code (130 line) for each new custom post type ... I moved the code to separated folder then I call it by

```
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type.php' );
```

in this way, I can have many ready custom post types as files and for each project, I can just add the file also for future maintenance instead of the scroll in very big 1000+ function file ... it will be a short file with a list of require_once and folder that has all the code in separated files

**MY QUESTION:**

- Does the require_once !! affect the speed of the website?
- when I should use it and when I should not
- whats the harm of overusing it to get a more arranged code?

the Question is more like PHP / server related than WordPress.

EDIT 1 : 
example lets say I have this file

**CASE 1**

1 file

*function.php*

```
// lots of code 

// 130 line of code to create custom post 1 

// 130 line of code to create custom post 2

// 130 line of code to create custom post 3

// 130 line of code to create custom post 4

// 130 line of code to create custom post 5 

// lots of code
```

**CASE 2**

total 6 files with the same amount of code + 5 lines of require_once

*function.php*

```
// lots of code 

require_once( 'library/custom-post-type1.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type2.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type3.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type4.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type5.php' );

// lots of code
```

*custom-post-type1.php*

```
// 130 line of code to create custom post 1
```

*custom-post-type2.php*

```
// 130 line of code to create custom post 2
```

*custom-post-type3.php*

```
// 130 line of code to create custom post 3
```

*custom-post-type4.php*

```
// 130 line of code to create custom post 4
```

*custom-post-type5.php*

```
// 130 line of code to create custom post 5
```

why I prefer the case to is smaller files easy to find and edit and can move any file to other project and just call it

I want to create some modules structure ... but can not harm the speed

Comment: You should not think about IO in context of PHP `include` or `require`. If you are approaching loads where IO really matters, includes will be in bottom of bottlenecks list.
IMHO you should look in direction of OOP features of language like classes, namespaces, packages and composer specifically to write more ... modern and modular code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWERS:

1. Does the require_once !! affect the speed of the website?

   - no
2. when I should use it and when I should not

   - you should use it when you need it to be included once in the whole PHP script, read http://php.net/require_once
3. whats the harm of overusing it to get a more arranged code?

   - it depends on the code that them contains, I mean that if the required file contains too much code **that will be executed** (not only function) the speed of the script that require it will be slowed down.

**Warning**: if the `require_once` fails, as per `require`, a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR level error` will be raised.

An example of file that may slow down your script when required may be:

```
<?php
    if($condition)
    {
        // execute lots of code
    }
    else
    {
        // execute lots of code
    }

    // execute lots of code

    // those does not slow down if not called
    function f()
    {
        // ...
    }
    function f2()
    {
        // ...
    }
    function f3()
    {
        // ...
    }
?>
```

The functions `require_once()`, `require()`, `include_once()` and `include()` simple do this: copy your content instead of the row when it is called.

Example:

If the file `functions.php` contains:

```
<?php
function f()
{
    // ...
}
function f2()
{
    // ...
}
function f3()
{
    // ...
}
?>
```

The following file

```
<?php
    require_once('functions.php');

    // some code
?>
```

will be as this:

```
<?php
    function f()
    {
        // ...
    }
    function f2()
    {
        // ...
    }
    function f3()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // some code
?>
```

**Edit**, about your **CASE**s

I suggest to you to do the combination of the two CASEs:

CASE 1+2

1 file `function.php` that itself require the 5 specific files:

```
// lots of code 

require_once( 'library/custom-post-type1.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type2.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type3.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type4.php' );
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type5.php' );

// lots of code
```

By doing that, you can include a file named `functions.php` that contains all the functions that all file can share together.

Inside this file, you can more compact the code by grouping all the similar functions in a separate file and require it inside it.

The result is that your code will be more readable and maintainable in prospect of future edits and more developer will be able to modify a single function's file simultaneously.

Comment: big thanks ... can you explain more about the last point. 

    it depends on the code that them contains.

and give some examples of the cases that it may coz problems?

Comment: thanks for the edit ... I see your last point now. 

I understand how it works ... its just like copy the code from the requested file and paste it into the original file ... right?

Comment: ok, I see the example .... but the slowing down will be the same if I did not use require_once and just added the same code to the file?

Comment: yes, it's true. But for a more readability and maintainability of your code I suggest you to put all functions in a separate file and then include it in every file you need using `require_once`

Comment: I edited my code and added real-life example ... kindly can you check

Comment: did not understand to combine case 1 and 2 ? 

you mean add all the content of 5 files in 1 big then the function.php make a require_once

Answer (score 3):

Using require_once, will include only the file once, but for purposes of code duplication, you may find yourself going to add require_once in 50% of your functions unless you add it in "index.php", which means you will end with loading the file even if it's not needed and that will happen for many many files.

In my opinion, I suggest to follow OOP, and create a class and follow PSR-4 to load the dependencies and use this class whenever it's needed.

Maybe people could have different opinions and could help better :)

Comment: about require_once I know it will include the files once ... 

but the point is this will take processing and time

for example when you load an image instead of loading 100 images adding then all in one big image load it it will make the site much faster 

as I think the require_once should work as 1 line of code. 

after it works it's like the file I called got a copy and paste in the place of the require_once line of code.

Comment: about the index, I make the parts of the page into separated files, for example, the vote. call it vote_blox.PHP 

then on any page I need it I call it by require_once

I know I can make it into a widget but I think  require_once will use much fewer resources than creating a widget ... plus it achieve the goal plugability

Comment: I understand your point of view, but I think sooner will turn into alot of require_once in the code and in case you decided to move these files to another directory, you will have to change all the require_once in your code, that's why PSR-4 standards are better :)

Comment: thanks you did great help your point is great but for this Question the second guy answer my Question in details

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that the time of reading a file is neglible to answer "no" to the first statement.

as php compile on execution time, if you only have 1 big file, you will read once, load into memory and compile and execute.

with multiple files, do the same but you must add de access time to each file (yes negible, but not zero) (also a difference between SSHD and traditional HD)

Also, reading to the memory consume memory, so functions not used will not increase execution time but will consume memory, garbage collector get the control over this, but anyway you read it before discard it. (little spike)

So the correct answer imho is that must be a compromise between time and memory.

If you want lower time, you need more memory and include less to avoid access times.

As always memory is expensive, so using less memory and increase the time just a little could be a better option. Also you get more readable code.

So the real answer is application dependant.
In you case working on a framework the answer is include files and add that little time to the execution.